# Navbar too small on mobile materialize meteor

Tags: css, meteor, materialize

I'm using Materialize for my navbar. I'm attempting to make the navbar collapsible into a sidebar on mobile as shown [here](http://materializecss.com/images/menu.gif). It does collapse into a sidemenu, but the navbar is too small on mobile as shown [here](http://s33.postimg.org/cibovlbu7/Screenshot_20160604_155617.png). How do I make the navbar narrower and taller so it is more usable on mobile? I'm also using this with Meteor using the materialize:materialize package if that is relevant.

Comment: Did you sort this out?

Answer (score 5):

Adding head tag with viewpoint meta  tag (once) before any given `<template>` tag solved the issue for me. Meteor, prior to rendering the page, looks up all head tags and adds them into header, and to display properly on mobile, you need viewpoint meta tag:

```
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
```